# Does the makefile of dcmtk3.6.3 in ubuntu14.0 have -g to debug?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, makefile, dicom, dcmtk

I want to debug the code of dcmtk3.6.3 with vs code in ubuntu14.0.

But i don't know whether the original makefile had the -g parameter.

I try to debug,but it does not work. So, should i add the "-g" in the makefile? And where to add?

this is the movescu of dcmtk in makefile.
 [image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to make it more specific/clear (see [help me is not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking for. That we download that piece of open source software? To figure what is written up in the makefile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the [INSTALL](https://support.dcmtk.org/docs/file_install.html) file that is shipped with the DCMTK would help, e.g. "./configure --enable-debug --ignore-deprecation" should do what you want (when using GNU Autoconf).